# Throwing exceptions when validation fails

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mvp

When I want to check the validity of an attendance being entered into the system, I perform following action.

**AttendancePresenter Class**

```
    void _View_OnCheckValidity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ExecuteAction performs exception handling in Base Class
        this.ExecutAction(() =>
        {
            ValidateAttendance();
        });
    }

    private void ValidateAttendance()
    {
        //DataService method returns true if the attendance is valid.
        var validity = _DataService.CheckValidityOfAnAttendance(_View.EmployeeID, _View.Date, _View.ShiftType);
        //Set the validity of the attendance in a View property.
        //So that View can stop execution if validity is false.
        _View.AttendanceValidity = validity;
        //If validation fails, throw an exception
        if (!validity)
        { throw new Exception("Invalid Attendance. Already there is a matching attendance for this employee"); }
    }
```

**View**

```
private void txtOutTime_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter & !string .IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmployeeID.Text) &  txtOutTime.Text != DefaultText)
    {                                
        OnCheckValidity(sender, e);
        if (this.AttendanceValidity)
        { OnEnterAttendance(sender, e); } //This line of code enters attendance into the DB
    }
}
```

Appreciate if you could review this code and give your feedback. Specially what I want to know is about the exception thrown in presenter if the validation fails. Is it acceptable? Is this is a standard use of `throw`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're throwing `System.Exception`. Don't do that. If you're going to have to throw an exception for a validation exception, throw a custom `ValidationException` exception.

You haven't shown the code where you `catch` and handle that exception, but it's going to have to look like this:

```
try
{
    // some code
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // handle the [validation?] exception
}
```

The problem with that, is that you don't *know* if the exception you're catching is due to a validation error, or if there's a division by zero, or if you ran out of memory, or if a database connection failed. With a custom exception type, you can do this:

```
try
{
    // some code
}
catch (ValidationException exception)
{
    // handle the validation exception
}
```

And any exception thrown that is *not* a `ValidationException`, will bubble up the stack.

---

That said, I wouldn't throw an exception for that. Exceptions should be for *exceptional* things. If you already know how you're going to handle it (show the error message in a message box?), why not just do that instead of throwing?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's anything wrong with throwing an exception for failed validation; failing validation is exactly the kind of circumstance which your model-level code can't handle, and should pass upwards.  I would never expect a `ValidateX` method to handle validation errors.

Comment: @sapi what if it were a function `IsValid ()`? Would you expect a Validation exception or a false? Exceptions are for Exceptional circumstances. And not for the everyday incorrect user input.

Comment: @Vogel612 If it's named `IsValid`, I'd expect a bool.  I certainly wouldn't expect a normal validation method (eg, database validation) to meekly return False when it gets bad data, though, and I've never used a framework which *doesn't* throw exceptions for failed validation.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> private void ValidateAttendance()
> {
>     //DataService method returns true if the attendance is valid.
>     var validity = _DataService.CheckValidityOfAnAttendance(_View.EmployeeID, _View.Date, _View.ShiftType);
>     //Set the validity of the attendance in a View property.
>     //So that View can stop execution if validity is false.
>     _View.AttendanceValidity = validity;
>     //If validation fails, throw an exception
>     if (!validity)
>     { throw new Exception("Invalid Attendance. Already there is a matching attendance for this employee"); }
> }
> ```

If you replace `valdidity` with the more standard `isValid` name, you could get rid of the comment saying `//If Validation fails...`. I think it just reads more naturally that way. Give it some breathing space around comments too. Removing comments like `set this to that` is also a good idea.

```
private void ValidateAttendance()
{
    //DataService method returns true if the attendance is valid.
    var isValid = _DataService.CheckValidityOfAnAttendance(_View.EmployeeID, _View.Date, _View.ShiftType);

    //So that View can stop execution if validity is false.
    _View.AttendanceValidity = isValid;

    if (!isValid)
    { throw new Exception("Invalid Attendance. Already there is a matching attendance for this employee"); }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't throw Exception, create a custom Exception as proposed @Mat's Mug and throw that one instead, otherwise you might trap an exception you didn't want to trap (ex : `MyDatabaseJustExplodedException`)!

I'd add that it is never good to have as much lines of comment as you have lines of code! Basically, comments shouldn't explain **what** you are doing but **why** you are doing it. If you need to explain what you are doing, something is wrong with your code.

I think the only comment that is worth its place is this one
`//So that View can stop execution if validity is false.`

I would change `AttendanceValidity` to `IsAttendanceValid`, it is way more clear what your property is in charge of.

Finally, I don't think you should have braces around one liners if it is to put them on the same line as your code. What I mean is either do this :

```
if (!validity) //changed by isValid as suggested @ckuhn203
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid Attendance. Already there is a matching attendance for this employee"); 
}
```

or this

```
if (!validity) //changed by isValid as suggested @ckuhn203
    throw new Exception("Invalid Attendance. Already there is a matching attendance for this employee");
```